# Cycles Netrender Returning Black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, network

I have a 2 node netrender setup that is fully functional with Blender render engine but not Cycles. When I do this it is rendering because it takes some time for it to return the blank images but it is not rendering the animation. If you need more information just ask nicely please :)

Comment: Does Cycles even support netrender?

Comment: @RolandiXor I believe it does. (at least, it [supports different render engines](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender#Client_2))

Comment: Hmm... do both of the machines work with cycles? Also, is it simply saving the images to the export directory (default is /tmp/)?

Comment: Cycles is supported, there is an option. This is a network render so it is rendering to servers that return the images to the master. The client downloads the frames from the master and it behaves like a normal render.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to fix your problem with netrender, but a possible alternative method you could use is to tell each server to write to a shared directory, enable *Placeholders* and disable *Overwrite*.

With *Overwrite* disabled, each server will check to see if a file already exists where it would otherwise write the next frame. If it does, it checks the next frame, and the next, and the next, until it finds a frame where no file exists. Then it will render that frame and write it.

Enabling *Placeholders* makes the server write a "dummy" file when it starts rendering to "reserve" that filename for the render when is complete. This ensures that one server doesn't start rendering the same frame another server is already rendering but hasn't written yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using blender 2.69 on Ubuntu. I downgraded my net render nodes to the version in the Ubuntu repositories (2.66a) and the problem went away. Never could get it working in 2.69. In my console output, 2.69 wrote .png files, and then complained that it couldn't find the .exr files.