# Is the Network Render addon able to render with openGL?

Tags: rendering, opengl, network

I would like to render an openGL preview using my rendering network, but there is no such option in the rendering engines dropdown. What can I do?

I built the rendering network with "Network Render" addon which is working fine with other engines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK netrender doesn't support this, as there is no opengl "render engine" defined in blender (as you noted). There is an opengl render operator, but it is not defined as a formal render engine.

However there is a simple alternative approach you might be able to use. See the following questions:

- [Render on more than one computer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15860/599)
- [Cycles Netrender Returning Black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5643/599)
- [How to use baked fluid with network render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5262/599)