# Net Render Outputs Black .exr Files, Regardless of Selected File Type

Tags: rendering, network

After watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOjQET1hAEQ) on setting up network renders, I set about trying to make one myself. However, regardless of what file type I have selected, it keeps outputting black .exr files.

I viewed a variety of links ([tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuerYVXsI7A), [tutorial](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender), [problem post](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-197422.html), [very similar StackExchange post with no answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5643/cycles-netrender-returning-black), [unanswered YouTube comments reporting the same problem](https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=VOjQET1hAEQ), and [a post about compositing .exr s](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?265284-exr-file-in-blender-Video-Sequence-Editor).) However, I still am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[Here's a link to the output and the file.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzl8ZZsYnq_XNm9IaUZORnMxSm8&usp=sharing)

Know I didn't write a lot, so please feel free to ask questions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Personally I've never had much success with the net render addon. Instead I've used [this approach](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5262/599) (also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15844/599 and my answer on the first SE question you linked).

Comment: @gandalf3 Hmm... well, I'll give that a go in the mean time. However, it'd be really nice if I could get it to work.

Comment: You may be interested in [flamenco](https://gooseberry.blender.org/announcing-flamenco-2-0alpha-release/)

Comment: What are you opening your exrs with? Have you tried opening your exr's in blenders uv/image editor? The images you have in your google drive above look right to me - I have opened a few files from both job1 and job2

Comment: @sambler GIMP and Preview. Will try that.

Comment: @sambler Opened it in the Blender Image Editor, everything appears fine. And while that's nice, it's a pain in the ass to have to save each file again and again and again. Outsides of using Python to script this, is there a way I can get it to output it into the file type I actually selected? And if I do have to script it, is it anything more than a matter of having it pull up file [n].exr, save as [n].___, repeat? And if I want to create a video, should I just import the image sequence into the Video Sequence Editor and roll from there? I know the Video Sequence Editor can't handle (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) multi-layered .exr s (as seen from http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?265284-exr-file-in-blender-Video-Sequence-Editor), so I have to convert them into something else, but is there anything else after that?

Comment: [This answer may be of interest](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33922/935)

Answer (score 2):

While multilayer OpenEXR files are a useful way to keep all the render results in one file, not every application supports them.

An easy way to get render output that can be used outside of blenders compositor is to save each part into a more compatible file, blenders file output node is useful for this.

[image]

As shown in the node properties, each output file can have it's own file format and any compositing can be included with the output.

Comment: Okay, I'll give this a crack.

Comment: Couldn't get that to work. Still does OpenEXR files, even when I told it to use png. http://i.imgur.com/HCJS3dh.png is my setup.

Comment: Check you have enabled 'use nodes' in the node window and compositing under post processing in render settings.

Comment: Both boxes checked, still nothing.