# How to save only Z-Pass Depth information as image?

Tags: image, saving, depth-map

Sometimes, I find it convenient to render a scene from the top with an ortographic camera and use the image as texture for another scene (kind of like using a flatbed scanner for scanning tree leaves or such).

Now, I have a scenario, where I am not interested in the image, but rather the depth information, to use it as a bump map in another project.

While I do know how to set up the render and have the result displayed properly in the render view (see screenshot), I can somehow not figure out how to save this specific view as a jpg image. (This is for a WebGL-project, so I'm trying to save on filesize - EXR is not the way to go here) But I can't seem to find the settings that would allow me to save anything other than the Color and Alpha pass...

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Enable Compositor and desired render layer (Depth) plug directly to Composite Node socket. If you want more output files at the same time add File Output nodes (there you can also specify other file formats to save than if defined by render properties).

Comment: Thanks! It might be added that a "normalize"-node has to be put in between the render layers and output node!

Would you like to post it as an aswer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Thank you. I think your Q is duplication  ... similar to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58966/2214 so I'm not going to A, but feel free to create an answer (it can be also accepted by you as well).

Comment: You're right. I voted to mark it as duplicate myself.